# php - Passing SQL query column to another .php page

Tags: php, mysql

I can't pass the `$name0` to admin.php of my project. I'm doing a login session to the login.php. But after querying both the username and password, i want the first name to appear at the admin.php, here's my work so far

```
        if(isset($_POST['btnlogin'])){
        $username = addslashes($_POST['txtusername']);
        $password = addslashes($_POST['txtpassword']);

       include 'db_connection.php';
       $sel_admin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='$username'";
       $rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
       $rs_count = mysql_num_rows($rs_admin);

       if($rs_count<1){
                        echo 'Invalid username!';
                        }else{
                        $admin_info = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin);
                        $adminid = $admin_info['user_id'];
                        $db_password = $admin_info['user_password'];
                        if($password == $db_password){
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $adminid;
                        $name0 = $_POST["'select user_firstname from users WHERE user_username='$username'"];
                                header("location: admin.php");
}
                                else{
                                echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: `$_POST["'select user_firstname from users WHERE user_username='$username'"];` you sure you meant this?

Comment: *"I'm doing a login sessioning"* - Did you start the session and inside all pages using sessions? On top of what's been said above, *what is that?!*

Comment: @Ismael. I'm not pretty sure, but I got an error that it is undefined. But I thought of it that the user id will somehow get the firstname if I query it.

Comment: @fred. Sorry I edited my post. I don't know what I said there is wrong. I'm telling that I'm login session for my login page. I didn't include the index.php. Though, i'm pretty sure it is not the case of the problem

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do with `$_POST["'select user_firstname from users WHERE user_username='$username'"];`

Comment: This is not really a good way of doing this. You should not pass raw queries in superglobals like post or get. Instead, query the details you need and stash them in the session variable or get string for the page rather than passing the query itself.
EDIT
Actually it looks like what you are trying to do is to get the query to define the post variable. In order to do that you need to run the query outside of quotes, however, this is not really a good way to do it either. You should know which field is going to generate the required post value and reference it directly.

Comment: @fred. I just want the specific column that comes with the login to display in another page.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is someone posts via a login form to your script. The values of that form appear in the $_POST array. That's where you get the `$_POST['btnlogin']` from. Unless you have a field in your form with the name `"'select user_firstname from users WHERE user_username='$username'"` the line in your code `$name0 = $_POST["'select user_firstname from users WHERE user_username='$username'"];` makes no sense.

I understand you want to pass the first name of the user to admin.php. You don't need to query that, because you just queried `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='$username'"`, so you have the first name already as `$sel_admin['user_firstname']`.

Best thing to do then is store the first name in the session:

```
$_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $sel_admin['user_firstname'];
```

`header("location: admin.php")` sends your user to admin.php where you can read out the first name from `$_SESSION['user_firstname']` - provided you do a `session_start()` both at the beginning of this script as well as admin.php

Comment: Thanks, i understand what you are trying to say. i also have a session. and it is in index.php where I have `if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))` in there, i just dont understand that I put the code you give in the index.php and still when it heads to admin.php, it says undefine variable.

Comment: If you have session_start() at the beginning of your index.php as well as your admin.php and you set $_SESSION['user_firstname'] in index.php and then send the user to admin.php where $_SESSION['user_firstname'] is an undefined variable, could you put: `print_r($_SESSION);` in admin.php and post the output here as a comment? (of course after removing any sensitive information)

Comment: Thanks, jeroen. Here what it says. Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\...\...\...\admin\admin.php on line 20.

Comment: Funny, I just got the same "Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION" error. It was because I forgot to put `session_start();` before. So, just to be clear: you need to put `session_start();` on top of BOTH scripts, login.php as well as admin.php. The you can set `$_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $sel_admin['user_firstname']` in login.php and you can retrieve it in admin.php using `$user_firstname = $_SESSION['user_firstname']`

Answer (score 0):

This code has been tested and will do it for you. Mark  it as correct answers as it will solve your problem.

first create table and insert users

```
create table users(username varchar(100), password varchar(100)
insert into users values ('sectona','sectona234');


<?php




$db = new PDO (
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 
    'root', // username

    'root44' // password
);
?>


signin.php


<?php
    error_reporting(0); 
?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>




<?php
session_start();

require("db.php");


//from form inputs

$username=strip_tags($_POST["txtusername"]);
$password=strip_tags($_POST["txtpassword"]);



/*

$username='sectona';
$password='sectona123';
*/

// validate username
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where username = :username');

        $result->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username
    ));

$nosofrows = $result->rowCount();

if ($nosofrows ==0)
{
echo '<br><b><font color=red><b></b>Username is Incorrect</font></b><br>';
exit();
}




//validate password
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where password = :password');

        $result->execute(array(
            ':password' => $password
    ));

$nosofrows = $result->rowCount();
//if ($nosofrows < 1)
if ($nosofrows ==0)
{
echo '<br><b><font color=red><b></b>Password is Incorrect</font></b><br>';
exit();
}


// check login



$statement = $db->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE username = :username
        AND password = :password

    ');






    $statement->execute(array(
':username' => $username,
':password' => $password));




    if ($row = $statement->fetch()) {

    session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['SESS_PASWWORD'] = $row['password'];
$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $row['username'];



$user=$pid=htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

echo "Welcome Mr/Mrs <b>".$user."</b> <font color=pink>you are signed in successfully. <br>Redirecting in 2 seconds</font> <img src=loader.gif>";


echo '<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "admin.php";
}, 2000);
</script>';

}else{

echo '<font color=red size=2><b>Either of your details is wrong. You are trying to use login accounts that belongs to another
person</b></font>';

}





?>


admin.php



<html><head></head><body>


Welcome <?php 
session_start();

echo htmlentities($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']); ?> 


</body></html>
```

Please mark it as correct answer if it solves your problem